# Spring Jackson not converting class from interface

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am posting the following JSON to a web server:

```
{
    "driver": "POSTGRES",
    "server": "teste",
    "port": "666",
    "sid": "teste",
    "schema": "teste",
    "datasource": {
        "name": "Novo datasource",
        "description": "",
        "type": "DATABASE",
        "user": "",
        "password": ""
    }
}
```

To this mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SomeInterface> save(SomeInterface object) {
    SomeInterface newObject = service.save(object);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(newObject, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

And I'm getting a 400 status code, mapped to a `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException` with no stacktrace at all.

I have 4 DB Entities that implement this SomeInterface, and what I want to do is to receive any of them in the controller, and pass it to Strategy on the Service.

Why is Jackson throwing that Exception instead of just converting the JSON?

**---EDIT---**

I'm running this from a Unit Test, and the only thing that shows up in the debug console is the assertion error exception as follows:

```
saveDatabaseDatasource(br.com.cds.connecta.presenter.DatasourceTest)  Time elapsed: 10.862 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers$1.match(ContentResultMatchers.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:148)
    at br.com.cds.connecta.presenter.DatasourceTest.saveDatabaseDatasource(DatasourceTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: How is Spring (Jackson) supposed to know which implementation to use for deserialization?

Comment: Turn your log levels to DEBUG to see more.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's what I want to know... I'll get the debug log.

Comment: Your question is lacking all the types involved in your log. You seem to be running a test, you should show that. You should really just show a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: im also looking for something similar. found one interesting post but with gson, http://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html. However i think something similar might be available for jackson also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using [Jackson's polymorphic deserialization features](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html), there's absolutely no way for Jackson to guess which of your four (or more) `SomeInterface` implementation to use as the target deserialization class. As such, Jackson fails to parse your JSON and throws up an exception to Spring.

If you turn your log level to DEBUG, you'll see a more specific reason.